# Vue js - filter a table with multiple column

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

i'm quite a beginner so this i probably obvious to you guys but... I'm making a filter in Vue js 2.0  that filter in any column. I came up with this

```
    computed: {
    filteredAndSortedData() {
        let result = this.testData;
        if (this.filterValue) {
            result = result.filter(item =>                
item.round.includes(this.filterValue) ||
item.cat.includes(this.filterValue) ||
item.player1.includes(this.filterValue) ||                                                                  
item.player2.includes(this.filterValue));
        }
```

here the jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/ebxsvac0/ of what i'm trying to do.

My question is how do I rewrite this code without hardcoding the column variable.
thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following instead:

```
if (this.filterValue) {
    result = result.filter(item => Object.keys(item).map((key) => item[key].includes(this.filterValue)).includes(true));
}
```

For every item - go over all of the keys (they are the column names) and check for everyone if the item includes the value you want to filter in that column.

Here is the update to your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebxsvac0/1/

Comment: Hi @Dekel, thanks for the jsfiddle. Made life easier. However the search is case sensitive. How to make it searchable regardless of CAPS or small letters. I tried making it toLowerCase but it stopped working can you update codes for me thanks :)

Comment: @Zee you should use `toLocaleLowerCase` on both the elements: `item[key].toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.filterValue.toLocaleLowerCase())`. Another option is to use regex.